trying to perform knowledge distillation using KL divergence loss . the loss is too high
KL divergence loss too high
I'm trying to perform knowledge distillation . For my student loss I have used cross entropy loss and for my knowledge distillation loss I am trying to use KL divergence loss.
Here is the code that I used for my KL divergence loss.
class KLDivLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,ignore_index=-1, reduction="batchmean", log_target=False):
        super(KLDivLoss, self).__init__()
        self.reduction = reduction
        self.log_target = log_target
        self.ignore_index = ignore_index

    def forward(self, preds_S, preds_T, T =1.0, alpha = 1.0):
        preds_T[0] = preds_T[0].detach()  # Detach teacher predictions
        pred_1 = torch.sigmoid(preds_T[0]/T) # white
        pred_0 = 1 - pred_1
        preds_teacher = torch.cat((pred_0, pred_1), dim=1)
        assert preds_S[0].shape == preds_teacher.shape, "Input and target shapes must match for KLDivLoss"
        stu_prob = F.log_softmax(preds_S[0]/T, dim=1)
        kd_loss = F.kl_div(stu_prob, 
                           preds_teacher, 
                           reduction='batchmean',
                           ) * T * T
        return {'loss': kd_loss}

The values that I am getting from this are extremely huge. I am simply adding my knowledge distillation loss and cross entropy loss from student model. Since my CE loss is very small this is all from the KLdiv loss. Could you tell me how to reduce the loss? Or if I am doing something wrong.
enter image description here
I tried using the KL div loss with temperature =1
my teacher model gave the output in the form of tensor [8,1,224,224] as it was used for binary prediction of pixel while my student model gave output in the form [8,2,224,224] where 0 belongs to class black and 1 to white.
so in order to match them up for KL div loss I used sigmoid function to get probabilities for class white and 1 - white probability for black. and then concatenated them to form a tensor of size [8,2,224,224] which would be similar to the student tensor.
and then I tried performing the KL divergence. the losses I got were extremely high

The main problem here is that you use reduction='batchmean' in F.kl_div. That would be right for a common classification problem, in which output of a model has shape [B, C], where B is batch size and C is number of classes. Note that the sum over the second dimension will give 1, as the model gives the probas of classes for each sample in batch.  In your case you may consider segmentation as pixel-wise classification, so that the value for each pixel is predicted independently. The number of classes C is 2, but B is not batch size any more,B=224x224x8 as each pixel is a separate "sample". So, there are two options to solve this problem:

Reshape tensors to [224x224x8, 2] before kl_div, for example, by using .view(-1,2) and continue using reduction='batchmean'
Calculate kl_div in this way (pay attention to mean and * 2):

kd_loss = F.kl_div(stu_prob, 
                       preds_teacher, 
                       reduction='mean',
                  ) * T * T * 2

